# image.display window in lua/torch

Tags: image, lua, torch

I am displaying images in torch using the `image.display()` function. However each time I call the function it creates a new window but I would like it to replace the existing one if that is possible. Possibly its something to do with the `image.window()` function but I can't figure it out.
Thanks.

Comment: answers are in this doc: https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/gui.md#res-imagedisplayinput-

Comment: could you please give an example? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ qlua
> require 'image'
> w = image.display(image.lena()) -- with positional arguments mode
> image.display{image=image.fabio(), win=w} -- with named arguments mode
```